# Invisible Mouse Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. On booting the mouse does not appear. I have no idea how to solve this issue. I have seen the forum and tried the command :

```
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop? or 16.04 LTS Server?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your mouse is recognized:

```
xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
```

If you get no output please unplug and re-plug your mouse and reboot.
Then run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

If that doesn't work run:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Also update and upgrade

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've successfully installed Ubuntu and presuming you've installed the Desktop version (as someone who'd be installing server wouldn't expect a GUI for that matter), then to add to Rayleigh's solution, try to see if this still occurs when running a Live version (boot from CD/USB) and see if the problem persists. Then hit Ctrl+Alt+T to bring up the terminal and follow Rayleigh's instructions.

However if you've successfully installed Ubuntu and did not notice there was no mouse during installation, then I wonder if you were installing Ubuntu server. But, if you meant to say "While installing..." then after running

```
xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
```

if the output doesn't include an entry with [XExtensionPointer] at the end, then you may also try

```
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

if it doesn't ask you to remove anything, then just type "Y" for Yes to continue. After it's compelete, run the xsetpointer full command again and if a new entry has been added, unplug and replug your mouse to see if that has resolved your issue.